# what is difference implement interface at cglib proxy?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cglib

I made 2 proxy object using ProxyFactory in Spring.
One proxy object used interface and one proxy object not used interface.
but not working jdk dynamic proxy. all proxy object used cglib.
The proxy object that implement interface call real method.
The proxy object that not implement interface has unexpected result.
What's the difference between two cglib proxy object?
The only difference between the two is the interface.

```
// Not implement interface
open class Person: AbstractPerson() {
}

abstract class AbstractPerson(var age: Int? = null,
                              var name: String? = null) {
    fun init() {
        this.age = 31
        this.name = "LichKing"
    }

    fun introduce(): String = "age: $age name: $name"
}
```

```
// Implement interface
open class PersonImpl: AbstractPersonImpl() {
}

abstract class AbstractPersonImpl(var age: Int? = null,
                                  var name: String? = null): PersonInterface {
    fun init() {
        this.age = 31
        this.name = "LichKing"
    }

    override fun introduce(): String = "age: $age name: $name"
}

interface PersonInterface {
    fun introduce(): String
}
```

```
// Test
class PersonTest {
    @Test
    fun implementInterface() {
        val p = PersonImpl()
        p.init()

        val proxyFactory: ProxyFactory = ProxyFactory()

        proxyFactory.setTarget(p)

        val proxy = proxyFactory.proxy as PersonImpl

        println(proxy.javaClass)
        println(proxy.introduce()) // "age: 31 name: LichKing"
    }

    @Test
    fun notImplementInterface() {
        val p = Person()
        p.init()

        val proxyFactory: ProxyFactory = ProxyFactory()

        proxyFactory.setTarget(p)

        val proxy = proxyFactory.proxy as Person

        println(proxy.javaClass)
        println(proxy.introduce()) // "age: null name: null"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin method's default option is `final`.
The cause is `introduce` method not be extend.
default option is `open` when using interface so it's could be extended.

gradle plugin `kotlin-spring` is only for spring annotations.
It does not work for abstract class.